# PDF to Structured Format

Tags: html, xml, pdf

I have tons PDFs that I need to convert to some structured format that I can interpret (HTML/XML/etc)

PDFs are in this format:
http://img840.imageshack.us/img840/5407/pdfv.png

I have tried so far a lot of softwares that convert to HTML but all of them have no capabilities to separate the images, they just take like a printscreen of the page without the text and then use this image as a background in the html, using css to position the text

Like this: http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/5015/examplelp.jpg

I have a bunch of PDFs so process each ones images manually is not an option. Does anyone knows any solution for this (even paid softwares)?

Comment: The images are not available anymore. Could you please add a recent link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while back and ended up writing my own solution. It's called [PDFX](http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/) and it's free to use. It converts PDF to a structured-format XML and also renders any bitmap images (not vector graphics) found in the PDF separately.

Example input/output can be found [here](http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/example). You might want to give it a try.

Comment: This is very good, the best solution I've seen so far, thanks a lot for sharing.

Comment: Wow! This works like charm. The link you gave for the example isn't working. And is it only available as an online service? How can someone use it for converting in bulk? I am doing my university project where I have to convert thousands of research papers into some structural format so I can perform some NLP task on it. Is it possible with this tool?

Comment: @RishabhGupta - sorry for the late reply, I've not been receiving notifications. I've not been maintaining this site for 7 years now. The example link was simply the result page ("Job Details") that you get by feeding the system this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2687974/pdf/btp220.pdf

PDFX had converted more than 700k articles before I had left the university. If you read the Usage guide on acceptable use, you should be fine with a few thousands (if it's still relevant to you)